# Getting variables from a file

Tags: variables, namespaces, lua

Supposed I have a "test.lua" file like this:

```
myVar = 5

Food = function()

end
```

If I load the file via loadfile or via Lua API (in C++ or whatever) and run it, the variables will be saved under the global namespace _G; however, I'd like to have them separately, like _test.myVar and _G.myVar. (The reason for this is that I want to have a list of the variables from that file only). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What [lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463090/getting-variables-from-a-file/4464172#4464172) said.

For additional robustness in the face of files that may not be from a completely trusted source, you should read about [sandboxing](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) at the wiki.

The key idea is to be careful about what global functions and variables are available to code executing in the context of your data file. An easy way to get a lot of control over that is to construct the environment table that supplies the globals to the script so that it only contains a white list of safe functions. You do this by constructing a suitable table, and then setting it as the environment of the freshly compiled script before calling it. [`lua_setfenv()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_setfenv) from the C API or [`setfenv`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-setfenv) from the Lua side can both be used on the object returned by a successful call to [`luaL_loadfile()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_loadfile), [`loadfile`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadfile) or one of their relatives in either the C API or from Lua, respectively. Once the  script is loaded and the environment assigned, the you run it with [`lua_pcall()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_pcall) or [`pcall`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pcall).

Don't forget to check everything for errors.

When the script completes, variables it created have been written or updated in its environment table, rather than `_G`.

Naturally, that environment table could use a metatable to make some of the globals you supply the script effectively read-only as well.

For additional control, some have taken the idea further and arranged to limit the number of virtual instruction cycles or real clock time allowed for the script to run. It is even possible to inspect the bytecode after loading for certain opcodes. That can be used to prevent even attempting to execute a script that contains a loop in many cases.

Answer (score 5):

Use `lua_setfenv` before running the script.

Comment: But note that both module and setfenv are deprecated: see http://www.luafaq.org/#T8.1.4 and http://www.luafaq.org/#T8.2.1. OK, the question was to do it from the C API, but things seem to have changed slightly in Lua 5.2.

Comment: Lua 5.2 has not been released. The current version is still 5.1, and `lua_setfenv` is *not* deprecated in 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
module('_test')

myVar = 5

Food = function()

end
```

Then, from some other file:

```
require 'test.lua' --> or loadfile('test.lua')()

print(myVar) --> nil
print(Food) --> nil
print(_test.myVar) --> 5
print(_test.Food) --> function
```